# On register post method - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data

When I register I get below error, But user is registered and I see a entry registered in MongoDB terminal.

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

## StackTrace

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [LivePrice] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.normalize(Response.java:1823)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.toAbsolute(Response.java:1743)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.encodeRedirectURL(Response.java:1208)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.encodeRedirectURL(ResponseFacade.java:417)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView.sendRedirect(RedirectView.java:610)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView.renderMergedOutputModel(RedirectView.java:320)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2549)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2538)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

## Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String register(ModelMap modelMap){
    modelMap.put("user", new User());
    return "account/register";
}


@RequestMapping(value="/register", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String register(@ModelAttribute("user") User user){
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    userService.register(user);

    return "redirect:../login";
}
```

## UserDaoImpl

```
@Override
public void register(User user) {

    mongoTemplate.insert(user);
}
```

## UserServiceImpl

```
@Override
public void register(User user) {
     userDao.register(user);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replacing

```
return "redirect:../login";
```

To

```
return "redirect:/login";
```

Worked.